# MVC: Dropdown Filter of Datatable interferes with UIHints

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I tried to implement a Dropdown Filter to filter my Datatable like here: [Individual column searching (select inputs)](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html).

This also works up to the moment when I try to use UIHints to style my output. I think the problem is that my javascript code looks for the old cell content, while the actual cell content has already been changed by my UIHint. What is the best way to make my Drowpdown Filter working anyways?

Thank you in advance!

Here is a part of my code:

**Status.cshtml** (Display Template for status)

```
@model short?

@if (Model == 0)
{
    <b>Not Set</b>
}
else if (Model == 1)
{
    <b>Created</b>
}
else if (Model == 2)
{
    <b>Approved</b>
}
else if (Model == 3)
{
    <b>Done</b>
}
```

**Index.cshtml** (View)

```
@model IEnumerable<data>

<h2>Data</h2>

    <table class="display" id="db_table" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.month)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.year)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.country)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.status)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (var i = 1; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ElementAt(i).month)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ElementAt(i).year)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ElementAt(i).country)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ElementAt(i).status)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
    @section scripts
    {
        <script src="~/Scripts/Custom/datatable.js"></script>
    }
```

**datatable.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#db_table').DataTable({
        ordering: false,
        paging: false,
        lengthChange: false,

        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns(3).every(function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo($(column.header()))
                    .on('change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                            .draw();
                    });

                column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                    select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                });
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found my mistake:

The UIHints edited my cell contents with different styling tags. For example a cell content `text` was made bold and afterwards looked like `<b>text</b>`. This means my javascript filtering function was looking for `text`, when in reality the cells looked like `<b>text</b>`.

In order to bypass this behavior I created a javascript function, which removes html tags:

```
function stripString(str) {
    return str.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
}
```

and used it on the input values:

```
var val = stripString($.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val()));
```

Then it works just fine!